# Laravel 5.4 struggling with relationships

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I need help with Laravel 5.4 relationships.

I have 4 tables:

users (fileds: id, name, etc.)

profiles (fields: id, user_id, first_name, last_name)

orders (fields: id, user_id, etc.)
order_items (fields: id, order_id, product_id, etc.)

A user can have one profile

A profile can have one user

A user can have many orders

An order an have one user

An order can have many items

In the models I have:

User:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

Profile:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Order:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}

public function order_items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
}
```

orderItem:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
}
```

I have two questions:

1.
When I show an order, I want to show the first_name and last_name columns from the profiles table.

In my controller I did this:
$user = User::find($order->user_id);

In my view:
{{ $user->profile->fullName() }}

Is there a way to get the name directly in the view and not fetch the user first in the controller?

2.

In my Order model:

When I view the order I want to display all the order items and the product name (product->name) for each item.

I'm very confused and don't know how to do this.

In my controller I tried:
1.

```
$items = Order::find($order->id)->order_items->with('product');
```

Got an error: Trying to get property of non-object

2.
    $items = Order::find($order->id)->order_items;

```
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item->product->name;
    }
```

Got an error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_item_id` = 1 and `products`.`order_item_id` is not null limit 1)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to do anything in view.

In you order model you need to create relationship with user table like this:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In view you just have to write something like this:
`{{ $order->user->profile->fullName() }}`

2. If you have not mentioned the relationship between product and orderItems. For the relation you have mentioned above, the `products` table must have a `order_item_id` column. Then only this statement is enough:

`$items = Order::find($order->id)->order_items`

or I would recommend to use the following line instead of above

`$items = $order->order_items`

because you already have the `$order` object so you don't need to query again with the `id`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why do I need to add order_item_id in the products table. The products table has id and the order_items table has product_id which is the relationship.

$order->order_items does not return the product name, how do I get the product name?

Comment: Ok, managed to get it to work: In my Product model I have hasOne orderItem and in my OrderItem I have belongsTo Product. Now $order->order_items gives me the product name as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do

   ```
   Profile::where('user_id', $order->user_id)->first();
   ```
2. Do

   ```
    Order::with('order_items.product')->find($order->id);
   ```

this should work for you

Comment: Thank you, but for the order with products I get this error:
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_item_id` in (1, 2))